# Replace Line with Matching Pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file filled with two line couplets, a header line that starts with `//` and ends with the line number surrounded by `|`, followed by a line of text that is variable in length. Here's an example, where `...` indicates that the file continues with sequential line numbers for many lines.

```
// *  *   -  - - *  |1|
textextextextextextextext
// *- *-*       * |2|
textextextextextextextexttextextextext
...
// * - * -*                          |41232|
textextextextextextext
```

I would like to find the line number, then replace the header line with `>linenumber`. This example file would be:

```
>1
textextextextextextextext
>2
textextextextextextextexttextextextext
...
>41232
textextextextextextext
```

I know this probably involves `/s` and `sed` or `awk` with a backreference, but I'm just can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sed is a good tool to do it:

```
sed -E '\%^//.*\|[[:digit:]]+\|% s/.*\|([[:digit:]]+)\|/>\1/'
```

Explanation:

- `\%^//.*\|[[:digit:]]+\|%` This is an address, i.e. the following `s///` command will only run on matching lines. It matches `//` at the start of a line, and somewhere later there must be a number between vertical bars.
- The substitution replaces the whole line with the captured number.

Answer (score 4):

A sed one-liner:

```
sed 's%^//.*|\([0-9]*\)|$%>\1%' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NF>1{$0=">" $2} 1' file
>1
textextextextextextextext
>2
textextextextextextextexttextextextext
...
>41232
textextextextextextext
```

The above assumes that `text` never includes `|`s.